# Why this function is not working without adding double quotes around the arguments?

Tags: function, debugging

```
 function symbols(shape) {
   alert ("This is a " + shape) 
}

symbols (circle)
symbols (star)
```

Comment: Strings always have quotes around them.

Comment: Thanks, I thought is considered just as an argument.

Comment: I'm a beginner in programming and I'm supposed to ask such questions. I can not understand why somebody down voted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be knowing data types in JS.

If you pass **circle** or **star** as argument without quotes then the argument will be interpreted as object (which is not your intension). 
As per you function definition it is expecting string, means you should pass string literal e.g. `symbols('star')` or you should have a variable containing string value e.g. `var circle = 'circle';
symbols(circle);`

Comment: Hi, can you please tell help me? Why is  the output of this code 6?   var x = 0 
while  (x < 6) {
x++
}
document.write (x)

Comment: @WaqasShah I assume document.write(x) is the line after while(...){..} block. The reason is, while(x<6) executes for x={0,1,2,3,4,5}. The latest value x can acquire is inside while-block itself i.e {x++}. Hence, for x=5, while block updates x to 6, but for x=6 while(6<6) fails and you have latest value of x=6.